# Using Spyder IDE, how do you return from "goto definition"?

Tags: python, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, spyder

### Description of the problem:

I like to jump around code a lot with the keyboard but I am hitting a wall of usability in Spyder IDE. I can use the "goto definition" feature to jump to the definition of some function but then I can't go back to where my cursor was (so it takes a while to manually find where I was before because there might be many lines of code).

So for example there is a constant `X=5` in the same file and when I use "goto definition" I can see what that constant is but then there is no way to go back. Or another example is a function from another file where "goto definition" takes me to that other file... but now I can't find the other file I was on (because there may be many files open).

In the 30+ year old `vi` you can goto the definition and return with <kbd>ctrl-]</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl-t</kbd>. In the 14+ year old Eclipse the equivalent to "goto definition" would be approximately <kbd>F3</kbd> to go to the definition. And then to return would be <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>left</kbd>.

running Spyder version 2.2.4.

### Question:

**Using Spyder IDE, can you return from "goto definition"? If you can, how do you return from "goto definition"?**

### What I've tried:

I have a keyboard shortcut for "previous cursor position" set to <kbd>Alt Left</kbd> but "previous cursor position" doesn't do anything when I hit the key. (The default keyboard shortcut is <kbd>ctrl-alt-left</kbd> which conflicts with the Cinnamon-dekstop-manager keyboard shortcut for switching workspaces and so I had to remap the above mentioned keyboard shortcut.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Spyder have a one strange [bug](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spyderlib/a-lVayczSKY). Shortcut "Previous cursor position" only work if "Source toolbar" is present.

Turn on "View -> Toolbars -> Source toolbar". You can try it.

Comment: tested on spyder v2.2.4 by doing: without the "source toolbar" --> use `goto definition` keyboard shortcut then `previous cursor position` keyboard shortcut --> no observed response. open the "source toolbar" --> use `previous cursor position` keyboard shortcut --> observed editor going to the first source definition (i.e. back where I started). Also tested with more than one level deep "goto definition".